# Tensorflow: tf.gfile.Exist and Env::FileExists return True with empty filename

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

One short question about Tensorflow.

Why is the return value of tf.gfile.Exist and Env::FileExists method true when the filename is an empty string?

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.gfile.Exists("not_existing_file")) # False
print(tf.gfile.Exists("")) # True
```

The cpp method shows the same behavior than the python method.

```
auto env = tensorflow::Env::Default();
std::cout << env->FileExists("not_existing_file"); # False
std::cout << env->FileExists(""); # OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolves to the current directory:

```
>>> tf.gfile.Exists("")
True
>>> tf.gfile.Exists(".")
True
>>> tf.gfile.IsDirectory(".")
True
>>> tf.gfile.IsDirectory("")
True
>>> tf.gfile.ListDirectory("")
['lib', 'local', 'pip-selfcheck.json', 'tensorflow-1.3.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl', 'bin', 'include']
>>> tf.gfile.ListDirectory(".")
['lib', 'local', 'pip-selfcheck.json', 'tensorflow-1.3.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl', 'bin', 'include']
```